# How to express "the types of the values under all existing keys are of some type" in generic constraints in TypeScript?

Tags: generics, typescript

The most natural idea seems to be

```
interface Generic<T extends {[key: string]: string | undefined}> {

}

interface Simple {
    id?: string;
}

function dummy(param: Generic<Simple>): any {}
```

But this does not work. It is understandable however, since an object `a: Simple` can possibly have other fields, whose keys may not be of `string` type.

One possible case where this is useful would be that "query parameters are all strings", so we want the type of `req.query` to be `{[key: string]: string | undefined}`. There is no problem in doing this with an object. But if we want to extend the definition, say, from "express", and use it in generic constraints:

```
export interface RequestWithQuery<T extends {[key: string]: string | undefined}> extends Request {
    /**
     * The custom typed query.
     */
    query: T;
}

interface DummyQueries { input?: string; }

function dummyController(req: RequestWithQuery<Dummy>, res: Response) {}
```

The following error would arise:

> error TS2344: Type 'DummyQueries' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [key: string]: string | undefined; }'.
>     Index signature is missing in type 'DummyQueries'.

The problem actually boils down to expressing "having **exactly** these fields", instead of "having at least these fields", I think. But is it possible in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something which is close enough:

```
interface Base {
    [key: string]: string;
}

interface Generic<T extends Base> {}

interface Ok extends Base {
    id?: string;
}

interface NotOk extends Base {
    id?: string;
    num?: number; // error: Property 'num' of type 'number' is not assignable to to string index type `string`
}

function dummy(param: Generic<Ok>): any {}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Base%20%7B%0A%09%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20Generic%3CT%20extends%20Base%3E%20%7B%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20Ok%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3F%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20NotOk%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3F%3A%20string%3B%0A%09num%3F%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20dummy(param%3A%20Generic%3COk%3E)%3A%20any%20%7B%7D))

The type checking fails in the definition of the interface instead of when using it as the generic type of `Generic` but the outcome is the same, if I understand what you want to achieve.